# Spring Security prolong JWT token expiration for each request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In our application we have to set expiration duration for JWT token to 10 mins. If the user calls the API within 10 mins, it will be valid, beyond that it will throw invalid token exception.

The catch is, if the user invokes the API at the 9th minute, the token validation should be extended to next 10 mins. So, we have to prolong the token expiration for each request to next 10 mins (more like Http sessions).

We use spring security AuthenticationProvider to do the validation, but not sure how to update the expiration time and send the updated token in response header. How we can achieve this in sprint security?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We couldn't find any solution to update the token and add it to response header in Spring Security. But the same can be achieved by implementing [**ResponseBodyAdvice**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyAdvice.html) interface and annotating the implementation class with **@ControllerAdvice**.

Hope this helps someone else.